# Return Value From Plugin Dialog

Tags: tinymce

I have added a plugin to open a html page in a dialog window

```
// Adds a menu item to the tools menu
editor.addMenuItem('helloworld', {
    text: 'Example plugin',
    context: 'tools',
    onclick: function() {
        // Open window with a specific url
        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'TinyMCE sitfe',
            url: 'test.htm',
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Close',
                onclick: 'close'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

test.htm looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <input value="testing"></input>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to add a function that inserts 'testing' into the editor window when the dialog is closed. Very similar to this question:
[How do I get the values from my TinyMCE plugin back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740763/how-do-i-get-the-values-from-my-tinymce-plugin-back)
however I was unable to open the links he provided. Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this post got me there:

[Get input field value from dialog box in TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156221/get-input-field-value-from-dialog-box-in-tinymce?rq=1)

I modified my test.htm to this and it works

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../compat3x/tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <input id="image-url" value="testing"></input>
    <input id="submit-image-url" type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
 <script>
    document.getElementById("submit-image-url").onclick = function(){
        var imageUrl = document.getElementById( 'image-url' ).value;

        window.parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand( 'mceInsertContent', 0, imageUrl );
       tinyMCEPopup.close();
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could this be done without relying on compatibility mode? I suppose there is a new way to do this in tinyMCE 4 that is probably better than using a fallback to tinyMCE 3 functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that I used for tinyMCE 4:

```
<script>
  function closeModalAndInsertText() {
    top.tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent('test');
    top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
  }
</script>
```